Plot species accumulation curve without vertical bars
I would like to make species accumulation curves for different sets of data from the same dataframe
datacum<- read.csv("FObrut.csv",head=T,sep=";")
Year<-as.factor(datacum$Year)
datacum$Year<-as.factor(datacum$Year)
str(datacum) 

accum_curve11w <- specaccum(datacum[1:11,4:48], method = "random")
accum_curve12s <- specaccum(datacum[12:35,48], method = "random")
accum_curve13w <- specaccum(datacum[48:56,4:48], method = "random")
accum_curve13s <- specaccum(datacum[36:47,4:48], method = "random")

w11<-plot(accum_curve11w, main = "w11", xlab = "Number of Samples", ylab = "Cumulative Species Count")
s12<-plot(accum_curve12s, main = "s12", xlab = "Number of Samples", ylab = "Cumulative Species Count")
s13<-plot(accum_curve13s, main = "s13", xlab = "Number of Samples", ylab = "Cumulative Species Count")
w13<-plot(accum_curve13w, main = "w13", xlab = "Number of Samples", ylab = "Cumulative Species Count")

plot(accum_curve11w, col = "black", lwd = 3, 
     xlab = "Number of Samples", ylab = "Cumulative Species Count", 
     main = "Species Accumulation Curve")
lines(accum_curve11w$sites, accum_curve11w$richness, col = "red", lwd = 2)  # Customize the line's color and width


Once I have plotted one of the accumulation curves, I'd like it to be a shades area, rather than vertical lines (see example below). I've searched for a solution but failed to find one. I asked ChatGPT for assistance but it didn't help either.

What can I do to get the right format? I'm trying to get it to look like this:

Also, how do I combine all of them into 1 graph?
I have a reproducible data snippet but not sure how to upload it here.

Use the output of dput(datacum) to provide the data.

check geom_ribbon() in ggplot2 package

Re-structed, edit {ggplot2} option, and adapted colours.
I think you can achieve what you are after by tweaking the answers from here.
1) As you do not provide data, we have created some non-sense data by using the in-built data set BCI of {vegan}.
 # 1) 
 library(vegan, quietly = TRUE)
 data(BCI)
 # I would do this different, but that's how you have written it
 accum_curve11w = specaccum(BCI[1:12, 4:48], "random")
 accum_curve12s = specaccum(BCI[13:25, 4:48], "random") 
 accum_curve13w = specaccum(BCI[26:38, 4:48], "random") 
 accum_curve13s = specaccum(BCI[39:50, 4:48], "random")
 l = mget(ls(pattern = "accum_curve"))

2) We re-arrange the data to use it with {ggplot2}, see 6) and 7). Also, to set a default, we find the range of the y-data across all four data series stored in l (we used tmp, but this does not matter).
 # 2)
 specaccum2df = \(l) with(l, data.frame(site = sites, richness = richness, sd = sd))
 tmp = do.call("rbind", lapply(l, specaccum2df))
 ylm = range(with(tmp, richness + sd * c(-2, 2)))

3) Next, we select some colours from R's default discrete colour palette. A highly recommended reference. Also, we add axes labels.
 # 3) 
 # colours
 n = length(l)
 i = seq(n+1)[-1]
 c1 = palette.colors()[i] 
 c2 = palette.colors(alpha = .15)[i]  
 # axes 
 xl = "Number of Samples" 
 yl = "Cumulative Species Count"

4.0) We plot accum_curve11w with a sensible choice of ylim such that additional data will be inside the y-range. We also set the arguments ci.type, col, and ci.col.
4.1) We add accum_curve12s, accum_curve13w, and accum_curve13s with lapply(). This could have been done with a for-loop as well. For this to work, we set the argument add of plot() to TRUE. The invisible() is not really needed.
4.2) We place a horizontally aligned legend on top. Please adjust to your needs. legend() is quite powerful.
 # 4.0)
 plot(l[[1]], ci.type = "poly", col = c1[1], ci.col = c2[1], 
      ylim = ylm, xlab = xl, ylab = yl)
 # 4.1)
 lapply(seq(n)[-1], \(i) plot(l[[i]], add = TRUE, ci.type = "poly", 
                              col = c1[i], ci.col = c2[i])) |>
   invisible()
 # 4.2)
 legend("bottomright", inset = c(0,1), xpd = TRUE, horiz = TRUE, cex = .5, 
        legend = names(l), col = c1, lty = 1)


5) In my opinion, this figure is difficult to understand. It might be better to generate one plot for each data series.
 # 5)
 par(mfrow = c(floor(n/2), 2))
 lapply(seq(n), \(i) plot(l[[i]], main = names(l[i]), ci.type = "poly", 
                          xlab = xl, ylab = yl, 
                          col = c1[i], ci.col = c2[i], ci.lty = 0)) |>
   invisible() 


dev.off() "shuts down the specified (by default the current) device", see documentation. As a side effect, it resets the par.
 # dev.off() # resets par

6) We could also use {ggplot2}; instead of l we use tmp here. Source identification can be done by id. We need id to differentiate groups/specaccum/data source.
I am no {ggplot2}-expert, i.e. there might be a more concise way to calculate and display CIs.
 # 6) 
 tmp$id = sub(".[0-9+]*$", "", row.names(tmp)) 
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(tmp, aes(x = site)) +
   geom_line(aes(y = richness, colour = id)) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c1) +
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = richness - 2L*sd, ymax = richness + 2L*sd,  fill = id)) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c2) +
   labs(x = xl, y = yl, colour = "Data Series") + 
   guides(fill = "none") + theme_minimal()


7) In analogy to 5) we should consider to create a plot per data series if there are many and/or a lot of overlapping is going to happen.
 # 7) 
 ggplot(tmp, aes(x = site)) +
   geom_line(aes(y = richness, colour = id)) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c1) +
   geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = richness - 2L*sd, ymax = richness + 2L*sd,  fill = id)) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c2) +
   facet_wrap(~id) +
   labs(x = xl, y = yl, colour = "Data Series") + 
   guides(fill = "none") + theme_minimal()


